# Why, in some cases, does multiplying a value with two decimal places by 100 result in a decimal value rather than an integer? In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, integer, numbers, decimal, calculation

In some cases, when I multiply a value with two decimal places by 100, the result is not an integer, but rather a decimal value with several digits after the decimal point.

I'm using JavaScript

For example, here are some calculations I tested to illustrate my question. I conducted the tests using the Chrome browser's console.

> 100*4.98
> = 498.00000000000006

> 100*4.89
> = 488.99999999999994

> 100*4.77
> = 476.99999999999994

> 100*4.61
> = 461.00000000000006

> 100*4.55
> = 455

> 100*4.88
> = 488

> 100*4.76
> = 476

> 100*4.02
> = 401.99999999999994

> 100*4.01
> = 401

As you can see, some cases produce integer values, which I understand to be correct. However, other arbitrary values result in decimals.

**Could someone explain why this happens, and how can I resolve this issue?**

Comment: Do the answers provided to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/18057908) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)